# Emails sent from a cronjob to a local mailbox

Tags: email, cron, sendmail

I have some cronjobs. These cronjobs send emails but I dont want to disable them with (>/dev/null 2>&1). I would like to know how can I deliver these emails to a local mailbox? Server doesnt accept connections from outside. So the port 25 is open only on localhost/127.0.0.1.

A solution to create an alias such as root: user@localhost is ok ? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an alias is one soluton, another is to add a line before the cronjobs you want to send email somewhere else saying:

```
MAILTO=localuseryouwantemailtogoto
```

Check out `man 5 crontab` for the full details.